# Using Vue props in an interpolated pug template

Tags: vue.js, pug

It's my first week with Vue/Pug components. I have this pug template:

```
p(v-if="firstProduct")
  Product indeed exists {{ firstProduct }}
  - var foo = "bar"
  a.btn.btn-primary(@click=`redirect('products/${foo}/${firstProduct}')`) Go to the Product page
```

**firstProduct** is a Vue.js props that I passed to the component. I can see the string:

```
   Product indeed exists my-really-cool-product
```

so the variable **firstProduct** exists and has the correct value, but if I click on the link I landed in "/products/bar/undefined". The local var is printed but the prop is like is not there. I tried several ways to "print" the variable but apparently the JavaScript template or:

```
 "redirect('products/" + firstProduct +"')"
```

just don't work. Why the local var works but the prop doesn't? Need I to "v-bind" something?

Comment: what is the generated html in browser?

Comment: <a data-v-7f341f7e="" class="btn btn-shopify-primary">Go to the Product page</a>

Comment: did you try `@click="redirect('products/'+foo+'/'+firstProduct)"`?

Comment: @aarkerio To see the generated html you should see from `View Page Source` not from DevTools. I guess you will see `undefined` there.

Comment: Try this https://pastebin.com/meYV74eb